# Is it possible to replace each capturing group in a regex with a different string

Tags: php, regex

If I have a regex like this: `(\.\d+)|([A-Z]\d{2}\.-)`

Can I replace capturing group `$1` with string a and capturing group `$2` with string b within one regex replace?

```
preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $value);
```

`.123A12.-` to `Value-aValue-b` or `.123funA12` to `Value-afunValue-b`

Comment: Need some more examples of input and output

Comment: Maybe you'll find some clues [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
<?php
$patterns = array ('/\.\d+/','/[A-Z]\d{2}\.-/');
$replace = array ('Value-a','Value-b');
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replace, '.123funA12.-');
?>
```

See [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b8498603f8830700c1b0cc9d50c1d7e170a71036) and [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for information.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, just use `$1`, `$2` and so on:

```
preg_replace($pattern, "$1_something_else$2", $value);
```

E.g. `.123A12.-` (which would match your expression) would then be replaced to

```
.123_something_elseA12.-
```

Comment: Hm I think my question wasn't clear what I need would be `.123A12.-` to `Value-aValue-b` or `.123funA12` to `Value-afunValue-b`